# Регистрация и авторизация.вместо db использовать XML

Tags: php, xml

Подскажите начинающему как в XML ключам задавать unique, как там устанавливать связи да и в целом как работать с XML вместо db

Comment: Работать с XML вместо db __очень больно__. Пока не поздно - вернитесь обратно к БД.

Comment: Это понятно, но такие условия((

Comment: XML — это не БД, никаких unique там нет, никаких связей тоже нет. Как работать с XML вместо db — вам придётся придумывать самостоятельно